# Function accessing cell range

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I don't find how to use cell ranges with functions.

I vainly searched some examples.

I wrote the following test. I get "Object variable not set" error on both "for" lines (one is without "RangeAddress", and the second is with it, because I'm not sure of the correct syntax):

```basic
function CHECKBZRANGE(cellRange) as integer
    dim nCol as integer
    dim nLine as integer
    dim i as integer

    for nCol = cellRange.StartColumn to cellRange.EndColumn
        for nLine = cellRange.RangeAddress.StartRow to cellRange.RangeAddress.EndRow
            i = i + 1      ' placeholder for some computation
        next nLine
    next nCol
    checkBZ_range = i
end function
```

This function is called with a cell like `=CHECKBZRANGE(A6:C9)`

Can someone explain how to use a cell range passed by argument ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Calc spreadsheets it is not possible to hand over CellRange objects as parameters to User Defined Functions. If you give a cell range as the parameter, then this will be always a variant array. So there are two possibilities.

Either you need the cell values in the function, then you can take the variant array and use it:

```
public function CHECKBZRANGE(vCellRangeValues as variant) as integer

    dim i as integer
    dim vCellValue as variant

    if not isarray(vCellRangeValues) then
        vCellValue = vCellRangeValues
        msgbox vCellValue
        i = i + 1
        CHECKBZRANGE = i
        exit function
    end if

    for each vCellValue in vCellRangeValues
        msgbox vCellValue
        i = i + 1
    next

    CHECKBZRANGE = i
end function
```

Can be used as: `=CHECKBZRANGE(A6:C9)`

Or you need really the cell range object, then you must give its positions as parameters:

```
public function CHECKBZRANGE2(lcol1 as long, lrow1 as long, lcol2 as long, lrow2 as long ) as integer

    dim i as integer
    dim oCellRange as object
    dim lRow as long
    dim lCol as long
    dim oCell as object

    oCellRange = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(lcol1-1,lrow1-1,lcol2-1,lrow2-1)

    for lCol = 0 to oCellRange.Columns.Count -1
     for lRow = 0 to oCellRange.Rows.Count -1
        oCell = oCellRange.getCellByPosition(lCol, lRow)
        msgbox oCell.AbsoluteName
        i = i + 1
     next
    next

    CHECKBZRANGE2 = i
end function
```

Can be used as: `=CHECKBZRANGE2(COLUMN(A6);ROW(A6);COLUMN(C9);ROW(C9))`

Hint: This will only be recalculated if either `A6` or `C9` has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible! Just activating compatibility to VBA.

```
Option VBASupport 1

Option Compatible

Function Addressing(R As Range)

Addressing = R.Address

End Function
```