# how to pass cellrange to a user defined macro paramenter

Tags: macros, libreoffice-calc

i would like to work with cellranges within my macro.

```
Function SumIfColor(SumRange)
    Dim oRange as object
    Dim oSheet as object

    ' Get Access to the Active Spreadsheet
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

    ' Get access to the Range listed in Sum Range
    oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(SumRange).RangeAddress
End Function
```

The question is how can I call this function with real cellRange object instead of String. Because getCellRangeByName works only with String variable.
Because when I call the function like this

```
sumifcolor(B1:B3)
```

I got the following error:
"Object variable not set"

I read some hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059048/function-accessing-cell-range) but it did not helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass an actual CellRange object.  One solution is to pass the row and column number, similar to the second part of @Axel Richter's answer in the link:

```vb
Function SumIfColor(lcol1, lrow1, lcol2, lrow2)
    sum = 0
    oCellRange = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(_
        lcol1-1,lrow1-1,lcol2-1,lrow2-1)
    For lCol = 0 To oCellRange.Columns.Count -1
     For lRow = 0 To oCellRange.Rows.Count -1
        oCell = oCellRange.getCellByPosition(lCol, lRow)
        If oCell.CellBackColor > -1 Then
            sum = sum + oCell.Value
        End If
     Next
    Next
    SumIfColor = sum
End Function
```

To call it:

```
=SUMIFCOLOR(COLUMN(B1:B3),ROW(B1),COLUMN(B3),ROW(B3))
```

The sum will be recalculated whenever a value in the range `B1:B3` is changed, because of `COLUMN(B1:B3)`.  However, apparently changing only the color of a cell does not cause it to be recalculated.